# How to update python in sql server?

Tags: python, sql-server

I have a Python project that uses the [keras](https://keras.io/) Library.
Now I want to transfer this to sqlserver ml service, but the Python sqlserver version is 3.7.1.
Is there a way to update the built-in version of Python in sqlserver?

```sql
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
      @language = N'Python'
    , @script = N'
import sys
print(sys.version)'
```

result:

```
STDOUT message(s) from external script: 3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64bit (AMD64)]
```

Comment: Have a read of [Upgrade Python and R runtime with binding in SQL Server Machine Learning Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/install/upgrade-r-and-python?view=sql-server-2017) or [Change the default R or Python language runtime version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/install/change-default-language-runtime-version?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: update V3.7.1 to 3.8.5 ?

Comment: @Larnu this will not upgrade Python beyond 3.5